# How to use Sliders in Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms

This question may seems stupid but I'm very new to Orchard and just wondering how use **Featured Item Slider module** in my home page. I followed the following instructions:

1. Created a new ContentType as HomePageSlider
2. Selected Slider and Autoroute in list of parts
3. Saved
4. Created a New Content as HomePageSlider
5. Chose an image
6. Filled the fields and marked it as HomePage
7. Published

But after I checked the home page, content shows in simple format and not in Slider format and instead of showing the image, only a relative link to image appears.

What should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Mello.ImageGallery module/widget for image sliding in Orchard CMS.
http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Mello.ImageGallery
for lightbox, slider options builtin.

Comment: thank you, i take a look it, but what about `Featured Item Slider`?

Answer (score 4):

Featured Item Slider is a module. You don't have to create types and parts to use it. Once you enable the module, you will see it in the left hand side navigation.

Answer (score 2):

I have a fantastic [tutorial](http://www.pepfry.com/tutorials/image-slider-in-orchard-cms-featured-item-slider) on [pepfry.com](http://www.pepfry.com/tutorials/image-slider-in-orchard-cms-featured-item-slider) for this issue. I have a complete tutorial where I show you all the steps to successfully install the '[Featured Item Slider](http://www.pepfry.com/tutorials/image-slider-in-orchard-cms-featured-item-slider)' with screenshots.

I also have a video on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DqMqsc-XE4w) where you can see the [Image slider working successfully](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DqMqsc-XE4w).

Regards!
Sumesh M.S